# Sheet for printing in Qt

Tags: qt, qt4

Is it possible to insert values from some QLineEdits in such a way to fill fields in a sheet ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think using the rendering facilities of a `QGraphicsView/Scene` would be a better approach. It would take a bit of tweaking but displaying a scanned image or photo of a form and allowing users to click where they want to add text would work pretty good. Then you could render the text parts of the scene to a printer that has one of the forms loaded in it.